# sudo chown "Operation not permitted" - how to resolve permissions to allow chown by admin or root users?

Tags: terminal, permission, extended-attributes

As sanity check I was `sudo chown`ing some folders due to having run some commands previously that generated some `root` owned files in my `$HOME`. I ended seeing an error in this process that got me curious:

> `chown: Library/Caches/com.mailplaneapp.Mailplane3/my@domain.tld/Downloads/151623a0c45f2b4_0.1.pdf: Operation not permitted`

`ls -l@ Library/Caches/com.mailplaneapp.Mailplane3/my@domain.tld/Downloads/151623a0c45f2b4_0.1.pdf` doesn't reveal anything overly remarkable in this regard:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 USERNAME  staff  335080 Aug 17  2018 Library/Caches/com.mailplaneapp.Mailplane3/my@domain.tld/Downloads/151623a0c45f2b4_0.1.pdf
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       284
```

I noticed this same thing from other files in this folder. Is there something I can do to strip whatever permissions might be preventing an admin / root user from modifying ownership via `chown`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by changing the attributes? Why do you want to change the ownership of this file? What commands did you run that created root-owned files in your Home? What MacOS version?

Answer (score 2):

Try either or both of these commands:

```
sudo chflags noschg '/path/to/file.ext'

sudo chflags nouchg '/path/to/file.ext'
```